# Create box plot using Vega-lite in Kibana

Tags: kibana, vega, vega-lite

I want to create a box plot that shows how the duration of performing of certain REST endpoint had been distributed in some time period. I would like to have many boxes - one for example for 10 minutes.

I push information about REST endpoint every 3 seconds. Here is example of such data. Foe example information about the /books endpoint. Total number of invocations in time period (3s), mean execution time and so on.

```
 {
      "_index": "metrics-2018-09",
      "_type": "doc",
      "_id": "LBIqIWYBcLDRF6t2O8JR",
      "_version": 1,
      "_score": null,
      "_source": {
        "@timestamp": "2018-09-28T17:11:47.751Z",
        "name": "http_server_requests",
        "type": "timer",
        "exception": "None",
        "method": "GET",
        "status": "200",
        "uri": "/books",
        "count": 0,
        "sum": 0,
        "mean": 0,
        "max": 0
      },
      "fields": {
        "@timestamp": [
          "2018-09-28T17:11:47.751Z"
        ]
      },
      "highlight": {
        "uri": [
          "/@kibana-highlighted-field@books@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
        ]
      },
      "sort": [
        1538154707751
      ]
    }
```

How can I create a box plot for It?

When I try to type "mark": "boxplot" Kibana says: "Invalid mark type "boxplot""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer from [elastic stack discuss](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/vega-lite-boxplot/150434)

> The boxplot mark is being added as part of vega-lite 3.0, and we're currently running version 2.4 in Kibana.